# Auto resize Winform- messing up the controls order

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, window-resize

I develop a winform with a big testbox and a button below.

[image]

I set the textbox Anchor to the 4 directions so when the winform is resized, the tetbox will be resized accordingly.
  However, the button below that should not be resized is covered by the bigger textbox.
How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not a C# kind of guy, but would it make more sense to Anchor Left and Top only. Is that even possible in C#? Or perhaps on resize recalculate, for example: button_top = box_top+height+buffer etc. Excuse syntax, I don't do C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up these anchors:

- **The large TextBox:** Top, Right, Bottom, Left
- **The Button:** Left, Bottom
- **The small TextBox:** Right, Bottom, Left

[image]

You might want to add a [`MinimumSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(v=vs.110).aspx) to the form to avoid messing up the layout when it's too small.

And here's a live demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer. How did you attach the demo video?

Comment: I used [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to capture the screen in Gif format then I uploaded it. Really handy tool to have. It's also open source and written in C#.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

1. Dock the textbox in the form using dock = **Fill**.
2. Add a Panel to the control and set it to dock = **Bottom**.
3. Ensure that the textbox is before the panel in the document outline (and not nested in it!). If you get this order wrong, the panel will appear obscured by the text box.
4. Adjust the height of the text box area by dragging the line between it and the panel beneath it. You must click the panel before you can drag this line.
5. Add your button and other control to the Panel. Look in document outline to ensure that they are properly nested in the panel.
6. Align the button and other control as desired in the Panel.

**Note:** To see the document outline window: View => Other Windows => Document Outline